# Authorizing XPC connections

Tags: macos, security, xpc

My application includes as a key component a kernel extension. That kernel extension is controlled by a system control socket. For security reasons, that system control socket only accepts connections from the superuser.

To communicate from my regular, non-superuser application, I have a SMJobBless helper to act as an intermediary. The problem is, I only want my application (signed by me) to be able to connect to this XPC service. Is there any way to verify the signature on the executable on the other end of the connection? If I can get the PID of the process on the other end, that is sufficient, I know how to verify the signature from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I can get the PID of the process on the other end

You can, using [xpc_connection_get_pid()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/xpc_connection_get_pid.3.html).

Comment: `NSXPCConnection` also provides the [`processIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSXPCConnection_reference/translated_content/NSXPCConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012168-CLSCHNSXPCConnection-SW13) property.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reading this in 2021, security research has shown that PIDs are **not** trustworthy because of their reusability. Here's a [good presentation](https://saelo.github.io/presentations/warcon18_dont_trust_the_pid.pdf) on the issue.

As of macOS 11, the [`SecCodeCreateWithXPCMessage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/3684978-seccodecreatewithxpcmessage) function is available which allows for determining the true sender of an XPC message. On older versions of macOS the undocumented function `void xpc_connection_get_audit_token(xpc_connection_t, audit_token_t *)` exists which can with a few more steps be used to accomplish the same thing.

I built a Swift XPC framework called [SecureXPC](https://github.com/trilemma-dev/SecureXPC) that uses both of these functions, so if you want to see how to use them take a look at the [`acceptMessage`](https://github.com/trilemma-dev/SecureXPC/blob/9fb3217b734d7eb9a3782d4a0daae9fbfbb71a6c/Sources/SecureXPC/XPCMachServer.swift#L322) function.